# CSS for a mobile then converting to tablet, desktop, and a larger desktop

Tags: mobile, size, media, desktop, tablet

I am starting to code for a mobile device (iPhone 5c) and then in my media query sections, I am putting more code that applies to larger sizes: Tablet (768px), Desktop (1024px) and a larger Desktop (1200px).

While I am coding for the mobile section, I am shrinking the width of my window on my own desktop (using google chrome) to the furthest it can be while I am coding. However, when I look at my phone and iOS Simulator with my URL plugged in, it appears as the Tablet version instead. It should not have the background color as "red" on the mobile, ONLY on the Tablet.

Basically: Mobile - not red. Tablet - red

When I plug it in my phone, it comes up red when it is not supposed to be. It looks like the Tablet version.

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Here is my URL: alyssamroth.com/responsive01.html

And this is my code so far:

```
html {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

body {
    font-family: "aktiv-grotesk-std",sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*=================== HEADER======================== */


nav {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #e54f26;
    /*padding: 0 0px 0 0px;*/
}

nav #logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

nav #contactIcon {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    float: right;
}

header #mountains {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-image: url(../img/mountain.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px


}

header h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.7em;
    margin-left: 55px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    font-family: "aktiv-grotesk-std", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}

header h2 {
    padding-top: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    color: #a7a8ad;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-family: "aktiv-grotesk-std", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}


/* ========== CONTENT ============= */


article h3 {

    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #101626;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: "aktiv-grotesk-std", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;

}


p {

    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #101626;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: "aktiv-grotesk-std", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-bottom: 20px
}

aside #ipad {
    padding-top: 76px;
}

aside #desktop {
    padding-top: 82px;
}

aside #phone {
    padding-top: 82px;
}

/* =============== Media Query for Tablets ===============*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

body {
    background-color: red

}


/* =============== Media Query for Desktops ===============*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

}


/* =============== Media Query for Large Desktops ===============*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
```

Comment: Alyssa your code seems to be working the way it should be. You change the background color in the tablet version of your media queries to red, and that color will apply to everything above that size. Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I re-phrased the question, hopefully you can understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I am seeing, see my scree shots:
Mobile - NOT red
Tablet - IS red

[image]

[image]